# Spring does not scan and register managed beans; @AutoWired injects nothing and #{SpringManagedBean} is unavailable in EL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mybatis

Spring does not scan and register managed beans in spring boot application.
I don't know how to configure for `Spring Boot + JSF + MyBatic` application.

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={""})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

}
```

MyDataSourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("com.jg.myapp.mapper")
public class MyDataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource; <----- it is also problem. cannot inject DataSource.

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("/mybatis-config.xml"));
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

JSF Bean ManagePostActionBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ManagePostActionBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ManagePostActionBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{PostService}")
    private IPostService postService;

    public void setPostService(IPostService postService) {
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    private List<Post> postList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        postList = postService.findAllPost(); <----- postService is null.

    }
    ......
}
```

src/main/resources
   - applicaiton.yml
   - mybatis-config.xml

applicaiton.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: root
    password: root
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skyjob?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

mybatis-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
    </settings>
</configuration>
```

src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\faces-config.xml

```
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver> 
    </application>
    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingPhaseListenerMulticaster</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>
```

src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.beyondjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>PrimeFacesOnSpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DB RELATED -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-02</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.34</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-02</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.34</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.34</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions of frameworks (boot 1.2.5 and 1.1.4). Also spring boot manages the versions for you already. As you are using spring boot your web.xml isn't doing anything. Are you running an embedded container or are you deploying a war. And what exactly isn't working?I would expect the name of `PostService` to be `postService` unless you are defining the name yourserl in @Service or @Bean. For the proper creation of a fat jar you are missing the spring boot plugin. All in all a lot of information is missing and things aren't as they should be in your sample.

Comment: +1. Overriding dependencies versions allready managed by spring-boot-starter-parent will cause you much trouble.